# iOS Xcode fill background image based on percentage

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Looking to fill the background image in Xcode iOS based on a percentage.

#### The Constraints

- The image must fill the entire screen (centered), so that the smallest dimension (width or height) fits. (Even if image becomes pixelated because it has a small file size.)
- This must work universal, both iPad and iPhone devices.

#### Examples

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UIImageView`. To make an image fill the screen, set `imageView.contentMode` to `ScaleAspectFill`.

To make UIImageView fill the screen, use auto layout. The easiest way is to add 4 constraints for `UIImageView`. Spacing to nearest neighbor = 0 will do. Like so:
[image: Screenshot from Xcode]

Or leading/trailing/top/bottom space to superview = 0, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a `UIImageView` with the `contentMode` set to `.ScaleAspectFill` and add it as the bottom subview of your view.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my first comment before reading yours so now yours just looks like you're talking to yourself. This answer is a working one, but if the user rotates their phone it won't update. So inside the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` method you should update your image view's frame. Also it should be `.ScaleToFill` rather than `.ScaleAspectFill`

Answer (score 0):

Set height and width of your image view to the width and height of your screen

```
var image:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))
```

Comment: And if the user rotates the device your answer is no longer a working one.

Comment: In that case you can check the device orientation in your code and if the case is for landscape orientation you can use the below code                                                                                        var image:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width/2, self.view.frame.height))

Comment: Why are you dividing the width by two?